# Groovy compilation error when using poi.jar for a data sink script

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, apache-poi, soapui

I am new to coding, below is a groovy script that I am using in Soap UI to dump response data into an excel sheet. I am getting error at line 55, '}' for closing if condition (which I believe is not the issue). Earlier I was using only jexl and it was working fine but then I switched to poi to be able to append data in same sheet and it throws error. I have already copied all the relevant jars in bin/ext.

[image: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script10.groovy: 55: unexpected token: } @ line 55, column 1. } ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: } @ line 55, column 1. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:143) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:111) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:237) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:167) at]

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import jxl.*;

def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def ReqHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("Search#Response")
def HotelCount = ReqHolder["count(//*:Property)"]
def tCNo = context.expand( '${DSS#TCNo.}' )

if (tCNo =='1')
{
    FileInputStream fsIP= new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls"));    
    HSSFWorkbook copy = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = copy.getSheetAt(0);

    CL = 0;
    rows = HotelCount.toInteger();

    Cell cell = null;
    cell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("TCNo.");
    cell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("HotelName");
    cell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("HotelCode");
    cell = worksheet.getRow(0).getCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue("BrandCode");

    for( tc_row in 1..rows){
        Cell box = null;

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_row).getCell(CL);
        String s0 = tCNo;
        cell.setCellValue(s1);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_row).getCell(CL+1);
        String s1 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelName");
        cell.setCellValue(s1);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_row).getCell(CL+2);
        String s2 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelCode");
        cell.setCellValue(s2);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_row).getCell(CL+3);
        String s3 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@BrandCode");
        cell.setCellValue(s3);

    }
    fsIP.close();
    FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls");
    copy.write(fsOP);
    fsOP.close();
}
else{

    FileInputStream  file = new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFsheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0):

    datarows = ws.getRows();
    col = 0;
    log.info datarows
    exrows = HotelCount.toInteger() + datarows + 1;
    log.info exrows

    for( tc_ro in datarows+1..exrows)
    {
        Cell box = null;

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_ro).getCell(col);
        String s0 = tCNo;
        cell.setCellValue(s1);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_ro).getCell(col+1);
        String s1 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelName");
        cell.setCellValue(s1);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_ro).getCell(col+2);
        String s2 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelCode");
        cell.setCellValue(s2);

        cell = worksheet.getRow(tc_ro).getCell(col+3);
        String s3 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@BrandCode");
        cell.setCellValue(s3);

}
    fsIP.close();
    FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls");
    copy.write(fsOP);
    fsOP.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 53 you are missing one closing bracket:

```
FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls");
```

It should be:

```
FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls"));
```

The same thing happens in line 91.

Consider using an editor with code validation and completion. You can choose from wide range of free to use IDE's like IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans and so on. IDEA for instance would quickly tell you that you are missing this closing bracket and you would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stepniak, for pointing me in the right direction. It had way too many errors and some really crappy codding. Its working fine now.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import jxl.*;

def grUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def ReqHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("Search#Response")
def HotelCount = ReqHolder["count(//*:Property)"]
def tCNo = context.expand( '${DSS#TCNo.}' )

if (tCNo =='1')
{

HSSFWorkbook copy = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet worksheet = copy.createSheet("SearchSink");

CL = 0;
rows = HotelCount.toInteger();

Row head = worksheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell0 = head.createCell(0);
cell0.setCellValue("TCNo.");
Cell cell1 = head.createCell(1);
cell1.setCellValue("HotelName");
Cell cell2 = head.createCell(2);
cell2.setCellValue("HotelCode");
Cell cell3 = head.createCell(3);
cell3.setCellValue("BrandCode");

for( tc_row in 1..rows){
    Row data = worksheet.createRow(tc_row);

    Cell box0 = data.createCell(CL);
    String s0 = tCNo;
    box0.setCellValue(s0);

    Cell box1 = data.createCell(CL+1);
    String s1 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelName");
    box1.setCellValue(s1);

    Cell box2 = data.createCell(CL+2);
    String s2 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@HotelCode");
    box2.setCellValue(s2);

    Cell box3 = data.createCell(CL+3);
    String s3 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_row]/@BrandCode");
    box3.setCellValue(s3);

}
FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new 
File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls"));
copy.write(fsOP);
fsOP.close();
}
else{

FileInputStream  file = new FileInputStream(new 
File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);

int datarows = ws.getLastRowNum();
col = 0;
log.info datarows
exrows = HotelCount.toInteger() + datarows;
log.info exrows

for( tc_ro in datarows+1..exrows)
{
    Row data = ws.createRow(tc_ro);
    Cell box0 = data.createCell(col);
    String s0 = tCNo;
    box0.setCellValue(s0);

    Cell box1 = data.createCell(col+1);
    String s1 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_ro-$datarows]/@HotelName");
    box1.setCellValue(s1);

    Cell box2 = data.createCell(col+2);
    String s2 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_ro-$datarows]/@HotelCode");
    box2.setCellValue(s2);

    Cell box3 = data.createCell(col+3);
    String s3 = ReqHolder.getNodeValue("//*:Property[$tc_ro-$datarows]/@BrandCode");
    box3.setCellValue(s3);

}
file.close();
FileOutputStream fsOP =new FileOutputStream(new 
File("C:/Users/129858/Desktop/Soap/Simplify_HTE/SearchSink.xls"));
wb.write(fsOP);
fsOP.close();
}
```